# returnKeyType for all input fields?

Tags: react-native, tcomb-form-native

How to set returnKeyType to all TextInput fields inside one application?

I'm currently using tcomb-form-native and have to define returnKeyType again for every field, I just want to define it once and should work in every component.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple good options

1. Create a *custom text input component*, and here you can create a stylised TextInput field for use across your entire application. You can then set `returnKeyType=whatever` in its props, and use this component for all your text input instead.
2. Use `react-native-global-props`, which seems to have been created for this exact purpose. [Here is the link to the repository for more information / instruction](https://github.com/Ajackster/react-native-global-props)

Comment: Lovely! react-native-global-props is the thing I needed! Thank you Ryan!